# dropping NaN in the pandas aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
data = {'A': [1, 2, None, 4], 'B': [1, 2, None, 4]}
x = pd.DataFrame(data)

     A    B
0  1.0  1.0
1  2.0  2.0
2  NaN  NaN
3  4.0  4.0
```

Now, I aggregate across columns as:

```
x.agg("sum", axis='columns')
```

This results in:

```
0    2.0
1    4.0
2    0.0
3    8.0
dtype: float64
```

In this case, it seems to be treating `NaN` as 0 which is not what I want. Is it possible to treat missing values as NaNs for the aggregation i.e. the sum be NaN for such cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculate the sum of the columns, skipping any missing values.

```
x.agg("sum", axis='columns', skipna=False)
```

output:

```
0    2.0
1    4.0
2    NaN
3    8.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, methods for computing descripting statistics have a `skipna` option indicating if missing data is included. It is `True` by default. You can set it `False` using `skipna=False` in the method argument. Then the `NaN`s will be skipped.

[Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html?highlight=skipna#descriptive-statistics)